# how can I convert a dictionary to a string of keyword arguments?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, keyword-argument

we can convert the dictionary to `kw` using `**kw` but if I want `kw` as `str(kw)` not `str(dict)`,
as I want a string with keyword arguments for code_generator,

if I pass

```
obj.method(name='name', test='test', relation = [('id','=',1)])
```

I want a function to return the string like

```
"name='name', test='test', relation = [('id','=',1)]"
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The same syntax is used to accept arbitrary keyword arguments.

Python 2:

```
def somestring(**kwargs):
  return ', '.join('%s=%r' % x for x in kwargs.iteritems())
```

Python 3:

```
def somestring(**kwargs):
    return ", ".join(f"{key}={value}" for key, value in kwargs.items())
```

Note that dicts are arbitrarily ordered, so the resultant string may be in a different order than the arguments passed.

Comment: Note `.iteritems()` is Python 2 syntax; in Python 3 it's `.items()`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10458567/4115031

Comment: Python3 update with use of f-strings: `", ".join(f'{x[0]}={x[1]!r}' for x in kwargs.items())`

Comment: `", ".join(f"{key}={value}" for key, value in kwargs.items())` is maybe even more Pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

The upper answer can not run properly on python 2.7.16, it should be

```
def somestring(**kwargs):
    return ''.join([('%s=%s' % x) for x in kwargs.iteritems()]) 


#A full example:

def RunCommandAndEnsureZero(*args, **kwargs):
    retCode = RunCommand(*args, **kwargs)
    if retCode != 0:
        kwargsString = ''.join([('%s=%s' % x) for x in kwargs.iteritems()])
        raise Exception("error command: \"%s %s\"" % (''.join(args), kwargsString))
```

Comment: use [] to let the generator run;
then use the ("%s=%s" %x) to format a proper string formatting;
finally join them