# What is the difference between dict.items() and dict.iteritems() in Python 2?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.x

Are there any applicable differences between [`dict.items()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) and [`dict.iteritems()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems)?

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict):

> `dict.items()`: Return a **copy** of the dictionary’s list of (key, value) pairs.
>
> `dict.iteritems()`: Return an **iterator** over the dictionary’s (key, value) pairs.

If I run the code below, each seems to return a reference to the same object. Are there any subtle differences that I am missing?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

d={1:'one',2:'two',3:'three'}
print 'd.items():'
for k,v in d.items():
   if d[k] is v: print '\tthey are the same object' 
   else: print '\tthey are different'

print 'd.iteritems():'   
for k,v in d.iteritems():
   if d[k] is v: print '\tthey are the same object' 
   else: print '\tthey are different'
```

Output:

```
d.items():
    they are the same object
    they are the same object
    they are the same object
d.iteritems():
    they are the same object
    they are the same object
    they are the same object
```

Comment: It's basically a difference in how they are computed. `items()` creates the items all at once and returns a list. `iteritems()` returns a generator--a generator is an object that "creates" one item at a time every time `next()` is called on it.

Comment: In your particular case, `d[k] is v` would always return True because python keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256: https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html When you create an int in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object:

`>> a = 2; b = 2
>> a is b
True`
But, `>> a = 1234567890; b = 1234567890 
>> a is b 
False`

Comment: @the_wolf I think would be better to add the python version of the doc you are referring to in the question.

Comment: Did `iteritems()` change to `iter()` in Python 3? The documentation link above doesn't seem to be matching up with this answer.

Comment: Not exactly, @GabrielStaples. iteritems() is removed from dictionaries Python 3, and has no replacement. However, for the same effect, you do use iter(). e.g. iter(dict.items()). See pep 469: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0469/

Comment: dict.iteritems is gone in Python3

Comment: @GabrielStaples in python3 dict.items() is roughly the same as dict.iteritems() in python2 (or rather dict.viewitems()), both operate as a generator O(n), where python2 dict.items() iterates over the dict and returns a list of tuples. O(n*2)

Answer (score 947, accepted):

It's part of an evolution.

Originally, Python `items()` built a real list of tuples and returned that. That could potentially take a lot of extra memory.

Then, generators were introduced to the language in general, and that method was reimplemented as an iterator-generator method named `iteritems()`. The original remains for backwards compatibility.

One of Python 3’s changes is that  `items()` now return views, and a `list` is never fully built. The `iteritems()` method is also gone, since `items()` in Python 3 works like `viewitems()` in Python 2.7.

Comment: Note that you have missed a step in the evolution: the Py3 behavior isn't the same as `iteritems()`. It actually makes a full sequence-protocol object that also reflects changes to the dict (and is backed by the dict itself, rather than a redundant list)- it's been backported to 2.7 as `viewitems()`.

Comment: I'd like to learn about this in greater detail, but my google-fu is failing me. Could someone point me to documentation, articles or source that would help me better understand this? @lvc?

Comment: @Stew the change is described in [PEP 3106](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3106/) and there is a bit more in [what's new in python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists)

Comment: Sorry for elaborating on this ancient question but do I understand correctly that **`iteritems()` is always preferable over `items()`** in Python 2.x?

Comment: @RubenGeert Most of the time, it doesn't matter. For really large dicts it might be preferable.

Comment: @RubenGeert. One place where it is *not* preferable is when you want to iterate over the original items, but make modifications to the underlying dict.

Comment: Is there any speed performance difference by calling two different methods?

Answer (score 106):

`dict.items()` returns a list of 2-tuples (`[(key, value), (key, value), ...]`), whereas `dict.iteritems()` is a generator that yields 2-tuples. The former takes more space and time initially, but accessing each element is fast, whereas the second takes less space and time initially, but a bit more time in generating each element.

Comment: Why is each element the same then?

Comment: Why would you expect them to be different?

Comment: The "copy" in the docs doesn't mean that the elements are copied (if you want that, use `copy.deepcopy`). It means that it's a copy of the dictionary items: if you do `items = dct.items()` and then modify `dct` by adding/deleting keys or `dct[k] = other_v`, `items` will stay the same.

Comment: I did interpret 'copy' as meaning a deep copy and that the elements would be different...

Comment: Nothing in Python is ever a deep copy unless explicitly documented as such.

Comment: The 'copy' in the documentation seemed most similar to `l1=l[:]`  -- i.e., a true copy versus just an added reference...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - Regarding "more space and time" : At what size of dictionary do they start to matter. Say I've a "large" dictionary `{1:'one', 2:'two', ... }` over which I want to iterate on a webserver and render the results. At what scale should I start to worry about choosing `.items()` vs `.iteritems()` for Python 2.7 ?

Comment: @buffer: Not really sure. My estimate would be 15-20 items, but I haven't tested that.

Answer (score 79):

### In Py2.x

The commands `dict.items()`, `dict.keys()` and `dict.values()` return a **copy** of the dictionary's **list** of `(k, v)` pair, keys and values.
This could take a lot of memory if the copied list is very large.

The commands `dict.iteritems()`, `dict.iterkeys()` and `dict.itervalues()` return an **iterator** over the dictionary’s `(k, v)` pair, keys and values.

The commands `dict.viewitems()`, `dict.viewkeys()` and `dict.viewvalues()` return the [**view objects**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), which can reflect the dictionary's changes.
(I.e. if you `del` an item or add a `(k,v)` pair in the dictionary, the view object can *automatically* change at the same time.)

```
$ python2.7

>>> d = {'one':1, 'two':2}
>>> type(d.items())
<type 'list'>
>>> type(d.keys())
<type 'list'>
>>> 
>>> 
>>> type(d.iteritems())
<type 'dictionary-itemiterator'>
>>> type(d.iterkeys())
<type 'dictionary-keyiterator'>
>>> 
>>> 
>>> type(d.viewitems())
<type 'dict_items'>
>>> type(d.viewkeys())
<type 'dict_keys'>
```

---

## While in Py3.x

In Py3.x, things are more clean, since there are only `dict.items()`, `dict.keys()` and `dict.values()` available, which return the **view objects** just as `dict.viewitems()` in Py2.x did.

#### But

Just as @lvc noted, **view object** isn't the same as **iterator**, so if you want to return an **iterator** in Py3.x, you could use [`iter(dictview)`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) :

```
$ python3.3

>>> d = {'one':'1', 'two':'2'}
>>> type(d.items())
<class 'dict_items'>
>>>
>>> type(d.keys())
<class 'dict_keys'>
>>>
>>>
>>> ii = iter(d.items())
>>> type(ii)
<class 'dict_itemiterator'>
>>>
>>> ik = iter(d.keys())
>>> type(ik)
<class 'dict_keyiterator'>
```

Answer (score 35):

You asked: 'Are there any applicable differences between dict.items() and dict.iteritems()'

This may help (for Python 2.x):

```
>>> d={1:'one',2:'two',3:'three'}
>>> type(d.items())
<type 'list'>
>>> type(d.iteritems())
<type 'dictionary-itemiterator'>
```

You can see that `d.items()` returns a list of tuples of the key, value pairs and `d.iteritems()` returns a dictionary-itemiterator.

As a list, d.items() is slice-able:

```
>>> l1=d.items()[0]
>>> l1
(1, 'one')   # an unordered value!
```

But would not have an `__iter__` method:

```
>>> next(d.items())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list object is not an iterator
```

As an iterator, d.iteritems() is **not** slice-able:

```
>>> i1=d.iteritems()[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dictionary-itemiterator' object is not subscriptable
```

But does have `__iter__`:

```
>>> next(d.iteritems())
(1, 'one')               # an unordered value!
```

So the items themselves are same -- the container delivering the items are different. One is a list, the other an iterator (depending on the Python version...)

So the applicable differences between dict.items() and dict.iteritems() are the same as the applicable differences between a list and an iterator.

Answer (score 14):

`dict.items()` return list of tuples, and `dict.iteritems()` return iterator object of tuple in dictionary as `(key,value)`. The tuples are the same, but container is different.

`dict.items()` basically copies all dictionary into list. Try using following code to compare the execution times of the `dict.items()` and `dict.iteritems()`. You will see the difference.

```
import timeit

d = {i:i*2 for i in xrange(10000000)}  
start = timeit.default_timer() #more memory intensive
for key,value in d.items():
    tmp = key + value #do something like print
t1 = timeit.default_timer() - start

start = timeit.default_timer()
for key,value in d.iteritems(): #less memory intensive
    tmp = key + value
t2 = timeit.default_timer() - start
```

Output in my machine:

```
Time with d.items(): 9.04773592949
Time with d.iteritems(): 2.17707300186
```

This clearly shows that `dictionary.iteritems()` is much more efficient.

Answer (score 11):

`dict.iteritems` is gone in Python3.x So use `iter(dict.items())` to get the same output and memory alocation

Answer (score 4):

If you have

`dict = {key1:value1, key2:value2, key3:value3,...}`

In **Python 2**, `dict.items()` copies each tuples and returns the list of tuples in dictionary i.e. `[(key1,value1), (key2,value2), ...]`. 
Implications are that the whole dictionary is copied to new list containing tuples

```
dict = {i: i * 2 for i in xrange(10000000)}  
# Slow and memory hungry.
for key, value in dict.items():
    print(key,":",value)
```

`dict.iteritems()` returns the dictionary item iterator. The value of the item returned is also the same i.e. `(key1,value1), (key2,value2), ...`, but this is not a list. This is only dictionary item iterator object. That means less memory usage (50% less).

- Lists as mutable snapshots: `d.items() -> list(d.items())`
- Iterator objects: `d.iteritems() -> iter(d.items())`

The tuples are the same. You compared tuples in each so you get same.

```
dict = {i: i * 2 for i in xrange(10000000)}  
# More memory efficient.
for key, value in dict.iteritems():
    print(key,":",value)
```

In **Python 3**, `dict.items()` returns iterator object. dict.iteritems() is removed so there is no more issue.

Answer (score 0):

`dict.iteritems()`: gives you an iterator. You may use the iterator in other patterns outside of the loop.

```
student = {"name": "Daniel", "student_id": 2222}

for key,value in student.items():
    print(key,value)

('student_id', 2222)
('name', 'Daniel')

for key,value in student.iteritems():
    print(key,value)

('student_id', 2222)
('name', 'Daniel')

studentIterator = student.iteritems()

print(studentIterator.next())
('student_id', 2222)

print(studentIterator.next())
('name', 'Daniel')
```

Answer (score -6):

dict.iteritems() in python 2 is equivalent to dict.items() in python 3.

Comment: This is incorrect. The difference has already been explained in previous answers.