# Find dictionary items whose key matches a substring

Tags: python, dictionary, substring, key

I have a large dictionary constructed like so:

```
programs['New York'] = 'some values...' 
programs['Port Authority of New York'] = 'some values...' 
programs['New York City'] = 'some values...'
...
```

How can I return all elements of `programs` whose key mentions "new york" (case insensitive)? In the example above, I would want to get all the three items.

**EDIT:** The dictionary is quite large and expected to get larger over time.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

```
[value for key, value in programs.items() if 'new york' in key.lower()]
```

Comment: Exactly. Just don't expect it to be fast if your dictionary is large.

Comment: @MarkRansom I was just about to add that my dictionary is quite large and expected to get larger. It has been doing `programs.get('new york')` up to now which has been very fast.

Comment: If going through all keys in the dictionary is too slow for your application, you need to build a datastructure targeted at this kind of query. That would probably be either some sort of word-based inverted index or a suffix tree.

Comment: @mensi. Thanks. I'm making the change now to see how it performs. I'll look into other data structures as well.

Comment: This answer can also be wrapped with an any condition to get a boolean for whether any key in the dict contains a provided substring/condition: `any([x for x in programs if 'new york' in x.lower()])`

Answer (score 11):

This is usually called a relaxed dictionary and it can be implemented efficiently using a suffix tree.

The memory used by this approach is linear over the keys, which is optimal, and the time of search is linear over the substring length you are searching, which is also optimal.

I have found this library in python that implements this.

https://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dyoo/python/suffix_trees/

Comment: It says, page not found.

Comment: I guess the linked page is now here https://www.hashcollision.org/hkn/python/suffix_trees/ but the code has not been maintained. There's a link to a fork but that is abandoned as well.

Answer (score 7):

You should use the brute force method given by [mensi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10484313/5987) until it proves to be too slow.

Here's something that duplicates the data to give a speedier lookup. It only works if your search is for whole words only - i.e. you'll never need to match on "New Yorks Best Bagels" because "york" and "yorks" are different words.

```
words = {}
for key in programs.keys():
    for w in key.split():
        w = w.lower()
        if w not in words:
            words[w] = set()
        words[w].add(key)


def lookup(search_string, words, programs):
    result_keys = None
    for w in search_string.split():
        w = w.lower()
        if w not in words:
            return []
        result_keys = words[w] if result_keys is None else result_keys.intersection(words[w])
    return [programs[k] for k in result_keys]
```

If the words have to be in sequence (i.e. "York New" shouldn't match) you can apply the brute-force method to the short list of `result_keys`.

Answer (score 5):

An `iteritems` and a generator expression will do this:

```
d={'New York':'some values',
    'Port Authority of New York':'some more values',
    'New York City':'lots more values'}

print list(v for k,v in d.iteritems() if 'new york' in k.lower())
```

Output:

```
['lots more values', 'some more values', 'some values']
```

Comment: `iteritems()` is no more https://stackoverflow.com/a/10458567/4539999

Answer (score 5):

You could generate all substrings ahead of time, and map them to their respective keys.

```
#generates all substrings of s.
def genSubstrings(s):
    #yield all substrings that contain the first character of the string
    for i in range(1, len(s)+1):
        yield s[:i]
    #yield all substrings that don't contain the first character
    if len(s) > 1:
        for j in genSubstrings(s[1:]):
            yield j

keys = ["New York", "Port Authority of New York", "New York City"]
substrings = {}
for key in keys:
    for substring in genSubstrings(key):
        if substring not in substrings:
            substrings[substring] = []
        substrings[substring].append(key)
```

Then you can query `substrings` to get the keys that contain that substring:

```
>>>substrings["New York"]
['New York', 'Port Authority of New York', 'New York City']
>>> substrings["of New York"]
['Port Authority of New York']
```

Pros:

- getting keys by substring is as fast as accessing a dictionary.

Cons:

- Generating `substrings` incurs a one-time cost at the beginning of your program, taking time proportional to the number of keys in `programs`.
- `substrings` will grow approximately linearly with the number of keys in `programs`, increasing the memory usage of your script.
- `genSubstrings` has O(n^2) performance in relation to the size of your key. For example, "Port Authority of New York" generates 351 substrings.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was thinking of this when mensi above mentioned an inverted index. At this point in the project, I will have to choose performance over memory usage. So I'll test this out as well.

Comment: Great answer for when performance is an issue.