# Create new dictionary based on keys from other dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries that (simplified) look like this:

```
dict1 = {'X(0,0)': 1, 'X(0,1)': 3, 'X(1,0)':4, 'X(1,1)':2}
dict2 = {'X(0)': 'area1', 'X(1)': 'area2'}
```

I want to create a third dictionary with the keys of the first one and the values of the second one, if the `dict2` key `'X(i)'` is part of the `dict1` key `'X(i,j)'`.
So the end result should be like this:

```
dict3 = {'X(0,0)': 'area1', 'X(0,1)': 'area1', 'X(1,0)':'area2', 'X(1,1)':'area2'}
```

I have tried following what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484261/find-dictionary-items-whose-key-matches-a-substring/10484313) but it is not exactly what I want and cannot make it work.

Comment: I don't understand that logic... I mean `X(1,0)` contains both `0` and `1`, why did you associate it with `area2` instead of `area1`? Also: why use a string? If you simply used tuples as strings it would be much easier... i.e. instead of `"X(0)"` and `"X(0,0)"` use `0` and `(0,0)` afterwards you can simply do `key1 in key2` instead of having to parse both...

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Note the 'X(i)' and 'X(i,j)'. So we only need to look at the 1st number in the (i,j) pair.

Comment: Not very general, but I think this works for  your situation: `{k: dict2[k[:3]+")"] for k, v in dict1.items()}`

Comment: Will the numbers in those keys only ever be single digits?

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes indeed I only care if the first number in the (i,j) pair is common. They are the result of an optimization, so I prefer to keep them like that so it makes it easier to keep track of what is going on. The numbers in the keys are not single digits, but I don't want them in the final dictionary anyway.

Comment: @PM2Ring in my case the dict1 has keys like 'X(i,j,k)' and dict2 like the ones shown above. But I only want to link the dict1 keys with the dict2 values basec on the first digit i that is why I didn't show the compete form.

Comment: Ah, ok. That's fair enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this: 
But the approach is more specific to your problem.

```
print {key:dict2.get(key.split(',')[0]+')')for key in dict1}
# {'X(0,0)': 'area1', 'X(0,1)': 'area1', 'X(1,0)': 'area2', 'X(1,1)': 'area2'}
```

Conversion of `X(0,0)` to `X(0)` do like this,

```
In [29]: 'X(0,0)'.split(',')
Out[29]: ['X(0', '0)']

In [30]: 'X(0,0)'.split(',')[0]+')'
Out[30]: 'X(0)'
```

Comment: Thank you @RahulKP. This did exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you create a temporary dictionary first (for the key look-up) and then make the final one:

```
tmp_dict = {key[:3]: value for key, value in dict2.items()}
# {'X(0': 'area1', 'X(1': 'area2'}
dict3 = {key: tmp_dict[key[:3]] for key, value in dict1.items()}
# {'X(0,0)': 'area1', 'X(0,1)': 'area1', 'X(1,0)': 'area2', 'X(1,1)': 'area2'}
```

this will work for single-digit coordinates only.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict3 ={}
for i in dict1:
    dict3[i]=dict2[i[:3]+")"]
```

For your case!