# better one-liner to flip keys and values of a dictionary

Tags: python

I've written a one-liner to accomplish this:

```
vocab_tag = dict(zip(*reversed(zip(*tag_vocab.items()))))
```

Can anybody write one that's more comprehensible/direct?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A readable and short [dict comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) is probably the best one can do:

```
vocab_tage = {value: key for key, value in tag_vocab.items()}
```

Pre 2.7, dictionary comprehensions don't exist, but we can replace them trivially with `dict()` and a generator expression:

```
vocab_tage = dict((value, key) for key, value in tag_vocab.items())
```

It's worth noting that this presumes there are no keys with the same value (as does the example in the question).

Answer (score 3):

## Performance + Readability

Considering time performance, [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) is the best solution. It is both readable and performant.

Given a dictionary, `a`, defined as

```
a = {'1' : 'a', '2' : 'b', '3' : 'c', '4' : 'd'}
```

the implementations perform in the following manner:

### Original

```
%%timeit
b = dict(zip(*reversed(zip(*a.items()))))
```

---

```
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.09 µs per loop
```

### [Gareth Latty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/722121/gareth-latty)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14131104/2087463)

```
%%timeit 
c = {v: k for k, v in a.items()}
```

---

```
1000000 loops, best of 3: 776 ns per loop
```

### [Noctis Skytower](https://stackoverflow.com/users/216356/noctis-skytower)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14132576/2087463)

```
%%timeit 
d = dict(map(reversed, a.items()))
```

---

```
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.38 µs per loop
```

### Modification to [Gareth Latty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/722121/gareth-latty)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14131104/2087463) using [`.iteritems()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) method

[If using < Python 3, `.iteritems()` will perform slightly faster and is more memory efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10458567/2087463).

```
%%timeit
e = {v: k for k, v in a.iteritems()}
```

---

```
1000000 loops, best of 3: 598 ns per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one-liner: `dict(map(reversed, table.items()))`