# print a dictionary of queues

Tags: python, dictionary, queue

How can I print a dictionary of queues without popping off the contents?
I have something like this:

```
>>> mac = '\x04\xab\x4d'
>>> mydict = {}
>>> if mac in mydict.keys():
...     mydict[mac].append("test")
... else:
...     mydict[mac]=[]
...     mydict[mac].append("test")
... 
>>>
>>> for key,val in mydict.Items():
...     print key
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'Items'
>>> for key,val in mydict.Item():
...     print key
```

and am wondering how I can display the contents of my dictionary...

Thank you!
Ron

Comment: It's `mydict.items()` with lowercase `i`.

Comment: Hoops, thanks. you may want to put this down as answer and i'll check it answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Rohit Jain correctly pointed out: there is no `Items()` method - there is `items()`.

Though (if you are using python 2), it's generally better to use generator approach - use `iteritems()`, `iterkeys()`, `itervalues()`:

```
>>> for key,val in mydict.iteritems():
...     print key, val
... 
�M ['test']
>>> for key in mydict.iterkeys():
...     print key
... 
�M
>>> for value in mydict.itervalues():
...     print value
... 
['test']
```

Note that in python 3, `items()`, `keys()` and `values()` return iterators.

Also see:

- [What is the difference between dict.items() and dict.iteritems()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458437/python-what-is-the-difference-between-dict-items-and-dict-iteritems)

Comment: In python 3.x `iter` methods were removed (they're now essentially the default)