# Skip an iteration while looping through a list - Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, python-3.x, counter

Is there a way to skip the first iteration in this for-loop, so that I can put a for-loop inside a for-loop in order to compare the first element in the list with the rest of them.

```
from collections import Counter
vowelCounter = Counter()
vowelList = {'a','e','i','o','u'}
userString = input("Enter a string ")
displayed = False
for letter in userString:
    letter = letter.lower()
    if letter in vowelList:
        vowelCounter[letter] +=1
    for vowelCount1 in vowelCounter.items():
        char, count = vowelCount1
        for vowelCount2 in vowelCounter.items(STARTING AT 2)
            char2, count2 = vowelCount2
            if count > count2 : CONDITION
```

How would the syntax go for this? I only need to do a 5 deep For-loop. So the next would Start at 3, then start at 4, then 5, the the correct print statement depending on the condition.
Thanks

Comment: It's already answered down there, just a note: use [iteritems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458437/python-what-is-the-difference-between-dict-items-and-dict-iteritems) instead of items for iterating over a dictionary. It will be much more efficient for large dictionaries.

Comment: @leeladam - that's true, but only for Python 2.x. In Python 3.x there is no `iteritems` anymore, as `items` doesn't create a new list anymore.

Comment: Slicing a list with [1:] as suggested below creates a new array. It is faster and more economic to use a slice iterator with itertools.islice() - see code below

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
for vowelCount2 in vowelCounter.items()[1:]:
```

This will give you all the elements of `vowelCounter.items()` except the first one.

The `[1:]` means you're slicing the list and it means: start at index `1` instead of at index `0`. As such you're excluding the first element from the list.

If you want the index to depend on the previous loop you can do:

```
for i, vowelCount1 in enumerate(vowelCounter.items()):
    # ...
    for vowelCount2 in vowelCounter.items()[i:]:
        # ...
```

This means you're specifying `i` as the starting index and it depends on the index of `vowelCount1`. The function `enumerate(mylist)` gives you an index and an element of the list each time as you're iterating over `mylist`.

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that "the first one" doesn't really have much meaning when dealing with a `dict`'s `.items()` and that some form of "cartesian join" would be much better expressed using `itertools.product`

Comment: @JonClements: yes, that's true.

Comment: I've received the error:
line 41, in <module>
    for vowelCount2 in vowelCounter.items()[1:]:
TypeError: 'dict_items' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @JamesDonnelly ah, you're using Python 3. In that case you'd need to do `list(vowelCounter.items())`.

Comment: So how would that work? What would be the syntax doing the [1:]

Comment: @JamesDonnelly altogether it would be `list(vowelCounter.items())[1:]`. You'd need to add `list()` call to ensure the `dict_items` is converted to a list.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you want is to compare each count to every other count. While you can do what you suggested, a more succinct way might be to use `itertools.combinations`:

```
for v1,v2 in itertools.combinations(vowelCounter, 2):
    if vowelCounter[v1] > vowelCounter[v2]:
        # ...
```

This will iterate over all pairs of vowels for comparison. Doing it this way, you may also want to check if `vowelCounter[v2] > vowelCounter[v1]` as you won't see these two again (this goes for this method or the nested for loop method).  Or, you can use the `itertools.permutations` function with the same arguments and just one check would suffice.

Comment: I get the error: 
line 62, in <module>
    for v1,v2 in itertools.combinations(vowelCounter, 2):
NameError: name 'itertools' is not defined

Comment: @JamesDonnelly you'd need to add the line `import itertools` to import the `itertools` module.

Answer (score 2):

To skip an iteration you can use the `continue` keyword eg:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for value in list:
  if value == list[0]:
    continue
  print(value)
```

Would give you:

```
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Slicing a list with [1:] as suggested by a few others creates a new array. It is faster and more economic to use a slice iterator with [itertools.islice()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

```
from itertools import islice
for car in islice(cars, 1, None):
    # do something
```