# pyglet image resources from dictionary

Tags: python, image, resources, pyglet

I have a question about pyglet image resource definition.

If I have lot of pictures can I describe them in a dictionary and make images with for loop?

Fast way:

```
images = {'pic1':'pic1.jpg',
          'pic2':'pic2.jpg',
          ...}

for (name, val) in images.items():
    # this is correct code
    name = pyglet.resource.image(val)
```

Normal way:

```
image1 = pyglet.resource.image("image1.jpg")
image2 = pyglet.resource.image("image2.jpg")
...
```

With other words I want to use 'name' as name of variable and declare this variable like playget.resource.image(val), where val is name of image.

Comment: yes and get: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'img1'

Comment: Not from the code you have here. Please edit your question with the full error traceback and the relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

The following would be more efficient use of [Dictionary Comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) and the generator method [iteritems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458437/python-what-is-the-difference-between-dict-items-and-dict-iteritems) (if you use python 2.x):

```
{key: pyglet.resource.image(value) for k,v in images.iteritems()}
```

or if you have a naming pattern (`'pic1'` => '`pic1.jpg`' etc):

```
{'pic%s' % index: pyglet.resource.image('pic%s.jpg' % index) for index in xrange(1, 1000)}
```

Comment: I edit my question. when i use the first row of code i get an error: "super(Player, self).__init__(img=resources.img1, *args, **kwargs)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'img1'"

Comment: Can you post your code (or part of it) of the Player and the resources?

Answer (score 0):

I think find the solution, may be is not the best, python is not my strong side, and if anyone have better approach let share it!
So this work for me:
for (key,value) in images.iteritems():
   vars()[key] = pyglet.resource.image(value)