# Python and Json

Tags: python, json

I'm trying out json since I have to work with Cisco API and I can't figure out how to loop through the json object.I can get my keys but i can't get the values.

I am using http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ to me understand json format but this is what I have so far..

json file :

```
{
  "queryResponse" : {
    "@rootUrl" : "\/webacs\/data",
    "@requestUrl" : "https : \/\/192.168.116.207\/webacs\/api\/v1\/data\/DeviceGroups\/42",
    "@responseType" : "getEntity",
    "entity" : {
      "@url" : "\/webacs\/data\/className\/15",
      "@type" : "className",
      "@dtoType" : "deviceGroupsDTO_$$_javassist_5196",
      "deviceGroupsDTO" : {
        "@id" : "15",
        "@displayName" : "String value",
        "clearedAlarms" : 1,
        "criticalAlarms" : 1,
        "groupId" : 2,
        "groupName" : "String value",
        "informationAlarms" : 1,
        "majorAlarms" : 1,
        "minorAlarms" : 1,
        "name" : "String value",
        "warningAlarms" : 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My python script :

```
import json

jsondata = json.load(open('data.json'))

for rows in jsondata['queryResponse']['entity']['deviceGroupsDTO']:
    print(rows)
```

it print's :

```
name
@id
warningAlarms
@displayName
informationAlarms
clearedAlarms
majorAlarms
groupId
groupName
criticalAlarms
minorAlarms
```

not sure what i'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jsondata['queryResponse']['entity']['deviceGroupsDTO']` is a dictionary.

Iterate over [items()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) to get key, value pairs:

```
for key, value in jsondata['queryResponse']['entity']['deviceGroupsDTO'].items():
    print(key, value)
```

Note that, in case of python2, you would better use [iteritems()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) in place of [items()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items).

See also: [What is the difference between dict.items() and dict.iteritems()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458437/python-what-is-the-difference-between-dict-items-and-dict-iteritems)