# Refer to dictionary element in 'for' loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, dictionary

If I have a list of dictionaries, is there a way to refer to a specific element within the for loop declaration?

Something like this:

```
dict_lst = [
  {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},
  {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},
  {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},
]

for d['a'] as dict_elem in dict_lst:
  print dict_elem
```

Or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no `as` clause in `for` statements.

But it's pretty easy to do this explicitly:

```
for d in dict_lst:
    dict_elem = d['a']
    print dict_elem
```

Or, more simply:

```
for d in dict_list:
    print d['a']
```

Or, if you want to get fancy:

```
for dict_elem in (d['a'] for d in dict_lst):
    print dict_elem
```

Or, just for fun:

```
for dict_elem in map(operator.itemgetter('a'), dict_lst):
    print dict_elem
```

Which you can wrap up as a reusable function:

```
def itemmap(dicts, key):
    for item in dicts:
        yield item[key]

for dict_elem in itemmap(dict_lst, 'a'):
    print dict_elem
```

---

As a side note, you actually can do `for d['a'] in dict_list:`, but that just reassigns `d['a']` (assuming `d` is already a dictionary) to each new dictionary in the list, which is usually a confusing thing to do. (It can be useful for obfuscated code contests…)

Comment: Ah cool. I've put off learning about generators for awhile - guess it's time to learn about them!

Comment: @vincent: This is one of the better parts of the official tutorial (see [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) first if you don't know them, then start at [Iterators](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) and read the rest of that chapter. Then, once you've got the basics, see [David Beazley's presentation](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression) like so:

```
>>> dict_lst = [
...   {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},
...   {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},
...   {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3},
... ]
>>> for dict_elem in (d['a'] for d in dict_lst):
...     dict_elem
...
1
1
1
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
for element in dict_lst:
    print element['some_key']
```

Comment: I think you meant `dict_lst[element]`

Comment: @FarmerJoe I didn't noticed

Comment: You still have it incorrect.  Should be `dict_lst[element]`.  When you do `for element in some_dictionary: ...`  you are iterating through the keys.

Comment: Ah sorry, you are correct, I should have looked closer at the sample data, I thought it was a dictionary, not a list of dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the fastest and Pythonic methods to do it, lean on Python 3:

```
for key, val in d.iteritems():
    print key, val
```

There is also a similar method `items` which does almost the same. `items` will create a list of tuples with key and value if you call it in the `for` loop statement. There is also a similar method `keys` which only returns you a list of keys.

`iteritems` will not generate a list of tuples when you call it in the for loop. [Each element will be evaluated in each loop cycle.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458437/what-is-the-difference-between-dict-items-and-dict-iteritems) So there is no initial overhead and extensive memory usage. If you break the loop it's better as well.