# write output file python from program

Tags: python

This is my program.  Everything works except the part where I need to put the bowler name, score and title (average, perfect, below average, above average).  How to I make sure that all parts get into the outfile?  Thanks so much!

***  OK, so I got the file output correct EXCEPT none of the titles were added.  I need the output to look something like this:

> Jane 160 Below Average
>    Hector 300 PERFECT! 
>   Mary 195 Above Average 
>   Sam 210 Above Average 
>   David 102 Below Average

```
scores = {}  



def bowl_info(filename):
    infile = open("bowlingscores.txt", "r")
    total = 0
    for line in infile:    
        if line.strip().isdigit():
            score = int(line)    
            scores[name] = score


        else:
            name = line.strip()
    return  scores

def titles():
    for name, score in scores.items():    
        if score == 300:
            print name , score,  "PERFECT!"
        elif score < average:
            print name , score,  "Below Average"
        elif score > average:
            print name , score,  "Above Average" 
        else:
            print name , score,  "Average" 

bowl_info("bowlingscores.txt")
numbowlers = len(scores)
total = sum(scores.values())
average = total / numbowlers
titles()

for items in scores.items():    
    outfile = open("bowlingaverages.txt", "w")
```

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with? Have you tried searching for "writing to a file in python"?

Comment: I was not sure how to make sure that the name, score and title (as defined in the function) were in the output file.  I think I have everything but the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to write to a file in python

```
file = open("newfile.txt", "w")

file.write("This is a test\n")

file.write("And here is another line\n")

file.close()
```

**in your case you forget to write() and to close()**

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually writing to the file:

```
with open("bowlingaverages.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for name, score in scores.items():
        outfile.write(name + ":" + str(score))
```

As a side note, you should always use the `with` syntax when opening files, [see here](http://sdqali.in/blog/2012/07/09/understanding-pythons-with/). This ensures that the files are close correctly no matter what. Which is something that you're not doing. Also your `bowlinfo()` function is not actually using it's parameter `filename`.

One last thing, if you are using python 2.7 then you should use `scores.iteritems()` instead of `scores.items()`. If you're using python 3 though then that's fine. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458437/what-is-the-difference-between-dict-items-and-dict-iteritems)

**EDIT**

You are not getting the titles in the outfile because you are just printing them in your `titles()` method. You need to save the titles somewhere so you can write them to the file. Try this:

```
titles = {}
def titles():
    for name, score in scores.iteritems():
        if score === 300:
            titles[name] = "PERFECT!"
        elif score < average:
            titles[name] = "Below average"
        elif score > average:
            titles[name] = "Above average"
        else:
            titles[name] = "Average"
```

Now you have the titles saved for each player, you can change my code above to:

```
with open("bowlingaverages.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for name, score in scores.iteritems():
        s = name + ":" + str(score) + " " + titles[name] + "\n"
        outfile.write(s)
        # if you still want it to print to the screen as well, you can add this line
        print s
```

You can easily change the format of what is printed/written to the file by changing the value of `s`.

Comment: I got this error:  TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Comment: Thanks so much!!  About the parameter of bowl_info...I should have either left it blank or defined filename?

Comment: It would be better to use 'with open(filename, 'r') as infile:` instead of your `open('bowlingscores.txt', 'r')` line. It's neater if you don't hardcode things like filenames into functions but pass them in as parameters.

Comment: Thanks!!  Could you help me with one more thing??   The titles are not printing to the file.  I have no idea how to include them in the outfile.  I get the correct info in the python shell but the outfile is missing the title.