# Using Argparse and Json together

Tags: python, json, argparse

I am a beginner to Python.

I wanted to know if Argparse and JSON could be used together.
Say, I have variables `p,q,r`

I could add them to argparse as -

```
parser.add_argument('-p','--param1',help='x variable', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-q','--param2',help='y variable', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-r','--param3',help='z variable', required=True)
```

Now suppose I wanted to read the same variables from JSON file, is it possible to do it?
So I could input the values either from command line or a JSON file.

JSON input file -

```
{
    "testOwner": "my name",
    "tests": [
        "test1",
        "test2",
        "test3"
    ],

    "testParameters": {
        "test1": {
            "param1": "0",
            "param2": "20",
            "param3" : "True"
        },

        "test2": {
            "param1": "cc"
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to set args from `JSON` or to specify `argsparse` options with `JSON` ?

Comment: As I mentioned I want to configure some variables either from from command line or from JSON input file.

Comment: Do you have to use a `JSON` file? `config` usually works better, what's the final structure of your program? `argsparse` and `config` modules are just a way to set settings- you can set those settings in any other way as well.

Comment: so the point is I could set these arguments from by command line, or i could get  them on a file by specifying which file to use. it doesn't matter if its JSON, but I thought it was simple to use. But I also have some structured input, so I think JSON is better.

Comment: In that case you want to look at `configparser` it's in the stdlib ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) if you need more structure my personal preference is `configobj` https://configobj.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configobj.html

Comment: You should specify what the `json` file could look like.

Comment: I don't see the same dictionary keys in the `json` file as in the `argparse` definition.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The `args` Namespace from `parse_args` can be transformed into a dictionary with:

```
argparse_dict = vars(args)
```

The JSON values are also in a dictionary, say `json_dict`.  You can copy selected values from one dictionary to the other, or do a whole scale update:

```
argparse_dict.update(json_dict)
```

This way the `json_dict` values over write the argparse ones.

If you want to preserve both, you either need to have different argument (key) names, or the values have to be lists, which you can append or extend.  That takes a bit more work, starting with using the correct `nargs` value in `argparse`.

---

The revised `parser` produces, with a test input:

```
In [292]: args=parser.parse_args('-p one -q two -r three'.split())
In [293]: args
Out[293]: Namespace(param1='one', param2='two', param3='three')
In [295]: args_dict = vars(args)    
In [296]: args_dict
Out[296]: {'param1': 'one', 'param2': 'two', 'param3': 'three'}
```

The JSON string, when parsed (`json.loads`?) produces a dictionary like:

```
In [317]: json_dict
Out[317]: 
{'testOwner': 'my name',
 'testParameters': {'test1': {'param1': '0', 'param2': '20', 'param3': 'True'},
  'test2': {'param1': 'cc'}},
 'tests': ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']}
```

I produced this by pasting your display into my Ipython session, but I think the JSON loader produces the same thing

The argparse values could be added with:

```
In [318]: json_dict['testParameters']['test3']=args_dict
In [319]: json_dict
Out[319]: 
{'testOwner': 'my name',
 'testParameters': {'test1': {'param1': '0', 'param2': '20', 'param3': 'True'},
  'test2': {'param1': 'cc'},
  'test3': {'param1': 'one', 'param2': 'two', 'param3': 'three'}},
 'tests': ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']}
```

Here I added it as a 3rd `test` set, taking (by conincidence) a name from the `tests` list.  `json_dict['testParameters']['test2']=args_dict` would replace the values of `test2`.

One way to add the args values to the undefined values of 'test2' is:

```
In [320]: args_dict1=args_dict.copy()    
In [322]: args_dict1.update(json_dict['testParameters']['test2'])
In [324]: json_dict['testParameters']['test2']=args_dict1
In [325]: json_dict
Out[325]: 
{'testOwner': 'my name',
 'testParameters': {'test1': {'param1': '0', 'param2': '20', 'param3': 'True'},
  'test2': {'param1': 'cc', 'param2': 'two', 'param3': 'three'},
  'test3': {'param1': 'one', 'param2': 'two', 'param3': 'three'}},
 'tests': ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']}
```

I used this version of `update` to give priority to the 'cc' value in the JSON dictionary.

Answer (score 22):

Turns out to be pretty easy with the following caveats

1. The setup overrides values in config files with values on the command line
2. It only uses default values if options have not been set on the command line nor the settings file
3. It does not check that the settings in the config file are valid

```py
import argparse
import json

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('--save_json',
    help='Save settings to file in json format. Ignored in json file')
parser.add_argument('--load_json',
    help='Load settings from file in json format. Command line options override values in file.')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.load_json:
    with open(args.load_json, 'rt') as f:
        t_args = argparse.Namespace()
        t_args.__dict__.update(json.load(f))
        args = parser.parse_args(namespace=t_args)

# Optional: support for saving settings into a json file
if args.save_json:
    with open(args.save_json, 'wt') as f:
        json.dump(vars(args), f, indent=4)
```

Comment: This can be improved by `parser.parse_args(namespace=argparse.Namespace(**json.loads(f)))`

Answer (score 7):

Given that your JSON file contains a dict of the form:

```
d = {"name": ["-x", "--xvar"], "help": "Help message", "required": True}
```

After creating the parser you could "unpack" the dict like so:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(*(d.pop("name")), **d) 
# Put the 'name' as name/flag and then unpack the rest of
# the dict as the rest of the arguments
parser.parse_args("--xvar 12".split())
>>> Namespace(xvar='12')
```

However this forces you to maintain the dict keys to fit the arguments name of the method `add_arguments`. You also do not have a simple/straight forward way of using more advance behaviors like using the `action`, `type`, `choices` arguments.

Also you would have to change the form of your dict to contain the various  arguments you want to use. One solution would be to have the name/flag as the key of the dict in a tuple and the arguments would be a dict:

```
d = {("-x", "--xvar"): {"help": "Help message for x", "required": True}, 
     ("-y", "--yvar"): {"help": "Help message for y", "required": True}}
for names, args in d.iteritems():
    parser.add_argument(*names, **args) # Use a similar unpacking 'magic' as the first example
parser.parse_args("-x 12 --yvar 42".split())
>>> Namespace(xvar='12', yvar='42')
```

**EDIT**
Given the comments from the OP it looks like he wants to **parse** values taken from a JSON file.

```
d = {"-x": "12", "-y": "42"}
args = []
for item in d.items():
    args.extend(item)
parser.parse_args(args)
>>> Namespace(xvar='12', yvar='42')
```

**EDIT 2**

Looking at the `argparse` documentation [this paragraph](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#fromfile-prefix-chars) maybe somewhat relevant.

Comment: You're probably using Python 3 which removed the `iteritems` method - as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10458567/2003420). Instead use the `items` method.

Comment: actually this is not  really what I am looking for. I wanted to know, if I can specify arguments using both command line or JSON file, for same set of arguments.

Comment: Are you trying to use the value of an argument from the command and if it's not provided use a default value from a config file ? In which case you could just have the values store in a file and use these with the `default` argument of `add_argument`

Comment: not really, i should be able to input the arguments from command line or from a file, if not they will resort to default values.

Answer (score 2):

Here is `defaults.json`

```json
{
    "param1": "from json",
    "param2": "from json"
}
```

and here is `args.py`

```py
import argparse
from pathlib import Path
import json

json_text = Path('defaults.json').read_text()
args = argparse.Namespace(**json.loads(json_text))

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--param1', default='from default')
parser.add_argument('--param2', default='from default')
parser.add_argument('--param3', default='from default')
args = parser.parse_args(namespace=args)

print(args)
```

running it gives the following output

```
python args.py --param2 'from par'
Namespace(param1='from json', param2='from par', param3='from default')
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed comment. I am trying to run your code with one of the variable to `parser.add_argument('--param1', default='from default', required=True)` and returns `error: the following arguments are required: --param1`. Can we overcome this problem? Could you please provide a suggestion?

Comment: If you flag it as `required` then it is required, and will fail if not provided via commandline.

Comment: This will neither validate the JSON parameters nor convert them into the expected types.

Comment: As the name of the file suggest, this sample is more suitable to provide default values from json file, and defaults are assumed to be valid

Answer (score 0):

Some of the answers here are limited in that they neither validate the inputs, nor convert them to the expected types. A simple solution is to construct a list of strings for `argparse` to [re-]parse.

If your config file is simple (consisting of flags and single-value options) you can do the following:

```
import argparse
import functools
import json
import operator


js = '{ "class": 10, "no_checksum": "True", "my_string": "Jesus is Lord"}'
da = json.loads(js)
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--no_checksum', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--class', type=int)
parser.add_argument('--my_string')
pairs = [ [f"--{k}", str(v)] if not v=='True' else [f"--{k}"] for k,v in da.items()]
argv = functools.reduce(operator.iadd, pairs, [])
parser.parse_args(argv)
```

This uses a list comprehension to build up a list of options and stringified (if necessary) values from the read JSON dictionary. Any option set to `"True"` is passed without an argument (this is for flags); note that this code does not handle `"False"` values. (If you want this, use `v in ('True', 'False')` instead of `v=='True'`.) The resulting `pairs` value is a list of lists (either pairs or single flags); this must be flattened (i.e. nesting removed) for `argparse`, which is what `functools.reduce(operator.iadd, pairs, [])` is for -- it iteratively and cumulatively applies an incremental add operation to the list, concatenating all sublists into one big list. (The `[]` initial value is there in case `pairs` turns out to be empty, which would otherwise break `reduce`.)

The result is:

```
Namespace(class=10, my_string='Jesus is Lord', no_checksum=True, test=None)
```

If your config file contains lists, the code is a bit more complicated:

```
js = '{ "class": 10, "no_checksum": "True", "evangelists": [ "Matthew", "Mark", "Luke", "John"], "my_string": "Jesus is Lord"}'
da = json.loads(js)
parser.add_argument('--evangelists', nargs='*')
pairs = [ functools.reduce(operator.iadd, [[f"--{k}"], [str(v)] if not isinstance(v,list) else list(map(str,v))]) if not v=='True' else [f"--{k}"] for k,v in da.items()]
argv = functools.reduce(operator.iadd, pairs, [])
parser.parse_args(argv)
```

This extends the previous code to 1) convert list items to strings, if they are not strings already (`list(map(str,v))`, which applies the `str` built-in function to all elements of `v`); 2) flatten inner list values.

The result:

```
Namespace(class=10, my_string='Jesus is Lord', no_checksum=True, evangelists=['Matthew', 'Mark', 'Luke', 'John'])
```

If your argument file is more complicated than this, you probably shouldn't be using `argparse`, I argue. This solution does have a limitation in that it may not correctly validate certain corner cases.