# Unpickle and output dictionary in file

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

I have a pickled file which contains the names and 3 scores of each student in a class. So far using:

```
import pickle
filename="friendlist.data"
f=open('Class6B.txt','rb')
storedlist=pickle.load(f)
for i in storedlist:
    print(i)`
```

I can only print out the names, how would i print out the 3 scores attached to each student?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `storedlist` is a dictionary, then looping over the dictionary with `for i in storedlist` will set `i` to the keys of the dictionary. If you want to print the values instead, iterate over the values specifically with:

```
for i in storedlist.values():
    print(i)
```

To get both the keys and the values, use:

```
for key, value in storedlist.items():
    print "{} --> {}".format(key, value)
```

Here, `items()` gives you the keys and values in a tuple, which can be directly unpacked into two separate variables (`key` and `value` above).

Also, if the dictionary has many items, it may be more efficient for you to use `itervalues()` or `iteritems()` to generate the values in the loop without fully building a list as described further [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458437/what-is-the-difference-between-dict-items-and-dict-iteritems).

Comment: Thank you, but i was hoping to print them out with both the name an scores, so that i could then sort the scores and show who had the highest

Comment: @Rutwb2 I've got that information in the updated answer