# getting one value from a list of values in dictionary

Tags: python

I want to get the first value for "Forest" but im getting an "o"

```
zones = {"Forest":[1,50]}

for area in zones:
    spawnChance = area[1]

print spawnChance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the code, use `dict[key]` to get te value.

```
zones = {"Forest":[1,50]}

for area in zones:
    spawnChance = zones[area][1]

print spawnChance
```

Answer (score 1):

Python dicts when used as iterables yield their keys. As a result, `area` is equal to "Forest" in your example.

Also, index of first element in array is *zero*, not one (I believe only Basic uses one-based lists/arrays).

To access both keys and values use `items` or, better, `iteritems` (consult with [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458437/what-is-the-difference-between-dict-items-and-dict-iteritems) for difference between them)

```
for key, value in zones.iteritems():
    spawnChance = value[0]
```

Also, if you don't really care about the key, you can just use `values`:

```
for area in zones.values():
    spawnChance = area[0]
```

Comment: I take it you either mean `values()` or `itervalues()` for your last code snippet? :p