# iterate dictionary from a function

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I'm having a problem iterating dictionary from a function.

```
def iteratedic():
    datadic={
    "one" : 1,
    "two" : 2,
    "three" : 3,
    "four" : 4
    }

    return datadic

def getdic():
    dictionary = iteratedic()
    for m, n in dictionary:
        print (m, n)

getdic()
```

It says

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: use  dictionary.items()

Comment: `for m, n in dictionary.items():`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate through the `.items()`:

```
def iteratedic():
    datadic={
    "one" : 1,
    "two" : 2,
    "three" : 3,
    "four" : 4
    }

    return datadic

def getdic():
    dictionary = iteratedic()
    for m, n in dictionary.items():
        print (m, n)

getdic()
```

If you print `dictionary` you'll see that you get `{'four': 4, 'three': 3, 'two': 2, 'one': 1}` . If you print `dictionary.items()` you get the list of the items. `[('four', 4), ('three', 3), ('two', 2), ('one', 1)]`.

Comment: Using a generator is even better. What about `iteritems()`?

Answer (score 0):

If we do `for i in my_dict`, then it will gives the `keys`, not `keys: values`. Example:

```
>>> a = {"one" : 1, "two" : 2, "three" : 3, "four" : 4}
>>> for i in a:
...     print(i)
... 
four
three
two
one
```

So if you do `for i, j in my_dict`, then it will raise an error.

You could use [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), it returns a list that saves all keys and values in tuples like this:

```
>>> a.items()
[('four', 4), ('three', 3), ('two', 2), ('one', 1)]
```

So you could do...

```
def getdic():
    dictionary = iteratedic()
    for m, n in dictionary.items():
        print (m, n)
```

Also, [`dict.iteritems()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) is better than `dict.items()`, it returns a generator(But note that in Python 3.x, `dict.iterms()` returns a generator and there's no `dict.iteritems()`).

See also: [What is the difference between dict.items() and dict.iteritems()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458437/what-is-the-difference-between-dict-items-and-dict-iteritems)