# creating a dictionary from a text file 2 values

Tags: python, function, dictionary

```
def makeDict(filename):
    with open(filename,"r") as f:
         dict_={}
         for line in f:
             (key,value1,value2)=line.split()
             dict_[key]=[(float(value1),float(value2))]

mylist=[]
for value1 in dict_:
     if number < value1 < number:
        mylist.append(key)
```

one last question and I should be done here. It appears that my values are still not coming out as floats because I am trying to check if the value is between 2 numbers and i get this error

> TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()

```
    newDict=makeDict("file.txt")
     >>> testdict(500,530,newDict)

    line 28, in testdict
    for k,v in newDict.iteritems():
 AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Comment: Could you provide the full error traceback?

Comment: The code you posted has indentation mistakes in the for loop.

Comment: in the code you pasted there is no print(d) .. is the variable `d` out of scope and not there in the function from where you are calling it? please post the whole code..

Comment: Could you include the code that does the comparison and causes the error?

Comment: Just FYI: you should add new info to your original question, instead of editing and removing old info.  If you completely replace your original question, it's confusing for other users who happen to view it.

Comment: Could you show the code for the `testdict` function?

Answer (score 2):

Your function `makeDict` does not return a value.

```
def makeDict(filename):
    with open(filename,"r") as f:
         d={}
         for line in f:
             (key,value1,value2)=line.split()
             d[key]=[(float(value1),float(value2))]
    # Return the dictionary
    return d
```

**EDIT**

The problem in your code is that when you iterate through a dictionary with only one value, in this case `value1`, it will only iterate through the keys. What you want is to iterate through the values which can be done with the method `.values()`

```
def makeDict(filename):
    with open(filename,"r") as f:
         dict_={}
         for line in f:
             (key,value1,value2)=line.split()
             dict_[key]=[(float(value1),float(value2))]

mylist=[]
# Iterate through the values instead
for value1 in dict_.values():
     if number < value1 < number:
        mylist.append(key)
```

The last error that you have is likely caused by the Python version you are using. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20329606/4428725).

> In Py3.x, things are more clean, since there are only dict.items(), dict.keys() and dict.values() available, which return the view objects just as dict.viewitems() in Py2.x did.

So you should change the code in `testdict` to `for k, v in newDict.items():`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`float()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float) function to convert your values to floating point numbers.

Also, you should [`close()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) your file after working with it, or wrap your code in a `with` block (which will close the file for you):

```
def makedict(filename):
    with open(filename,"r") as f:
        d={}
        for line in f:
            (key,value1,value2)=line.split()
            d[key]=(float(value1),float(value2))
    return d
```

Finally, don't use `dict` as a variable name, because it already exists as a builtin.  Use `dict_` instead (or another name altogether):

```
dict_ = makeDict["file.txt"]
```

**EDIT**

Take this with a grain of salt, as it's just a guess based on the info in your question, but you want to change this:

```
for value in dict_:
    if number < value1 < number:
         mylist.append(key)
```

to this:

```
for k, v in dict_.items():
    if number < v[0] < number:
        mylist.append(k)
```

Comment: so is that all i need to do to turn them into a dictionary?

Comment: Yup.  If you are encountering an error, just edit your post above for more help.

Comment: im just curious is there a way to print(d) just to check or anything cuz everything ive tried ends up saying d isnt defined

Comment: Sure; you could `print d` to see the current value for `d`.  If you copy/paste the exact error you are getting to your question, that's a huge help.

Comment: Just edited my answer per the additional info in your question.

Comment: and how would i go about returning the key after? or appending to a list

Comment: Just edited my answer.  Since you are new to SO, if that answers your question(s), it's a good practice to accept the answer so that other folks can learn from your post.

Comment: Use `dict_.items()` instead of `dict_.iteritems()` if you are using Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
def makedict(filename):
    filename=open(filename,"r")
    d={}
    for line in filename:
         (key,value1,value2)=line.split()
          d[key]=(float(value1),float(value2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
def makedict(fname):
    filename=open(fname,"r")
    d={}
    for line in filename:
         (key,value1,value2)=line.split()
         d[key]=[(value1),(value2)]
    print(d) ## print the dictionary
```

Here you are storing the values as a list.

For example :

File -

```
A B C
1 2 E
3 4 E
5 6 E
7 8 E
```

Output (dictionary)-

```
{'3': ['4', 'E'], '7': ['8', 'E'], 'A': ['B', 'C'], '5': ['6', 'E'], '1': ['2', 'E']}
```

Here `A,1,3,..` are keys and `['B', 'C'], ['2', 'E'], ..` are corresponding values.