# How can I add/substract an integer to every value of an dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

As the title indicates, i have a dictionary that looks like similar to this:

```
dic = {0: 3.2, 1: 3.7, 2: 4.2, 3: 4.7, 4: 5.2, 5: 5.7}
```

I now want to add or substract an integer value to every value from the dic, but my simple attempt

```
dic.values() = dic.values() + 1
```

didn't work, since we use the .values() function here. Is there a fast and simple way to modify every value of an dictionary in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Broadcasted addition cannot be applied to a list (or `dict_values` object).

Use a `for` loop instead to update the value at each key:

```
for k in dic:
    dic[k] += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just do,

```
for key in dic: dic[key] += 1

In [12]: dic
Out[12]: {0: 5.2, 1: 5.7, 2: 6.2, 3: 6.7, 4: 7.2, 5: 7.7}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, you could also use a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> dic = {0: 3.2, 1: 3.7, 2: 4.2, 3: 4.7, 4: 5.2, 5: 5.7}
>>> dic = {k:v+1 for k,v in dic.iteritems()}
>>> dic
{0: 4.2, 1: 4.7, 2: 5.2, 3: 5.7, 4: 6.2, 5: 6.7}
```

Note that I have used `iteritems()`, rather than `items()`, as it avoids creating in intermediate list. Only really important if your dict is large, but I thought I'd mention it. Using `iteritems` is more similar to writing the `for` loop, in that we only iterate through the dict once.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458437/what-is-the-difference-between-dict-items-and-dict-iteritems) answer for more detail on the difference between the two methods.

Also note (as mentioned in the linked answer) that `iteritems()` is Python 2, for Python 3, `items()` returns a generator anyway.