# get original key set from defaultdict

Tags: python, defaultdict

Is there a way to get the original/consistent list of keys from defaultdict even when non existing keys were requested?

```
from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: 'default', {'key1': 'value1', 'key2' :'value2'})
>>>
>>> d.keys()
['key2', 'key1']
>>> d['bla']
'default'
>>> d.keys() # how to get the same: ['key2', 'key1']
['key2', 'key1', 'bla']
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to exclude. the keys that has the default value!

```
>>> [i for i in d if d[i]!=d.default_factory()]
['key2', 'key1']
```

Time comparison with method suggested by Jean,

```
>>> def funct(a=None,b=None,c=None):
...     s=time.time()
...     eval(a)
...     print time.time()-s
...
>>> funct("[i for i in d if d[i]!=d.default_factory()]")
9.29832458496e-05
>>> funct("[k for k,v in d.items() if v!=d.default_factory()]")
0.000100135803223
>>> ###storing the default value to a variable and using the same in the list comprehension reduces the time to a certain extent!
>>> defa=d.default_factory()
>>> funct("[i for i in d if d[i]!=defa]")
8.82148742676e-05
>>> funct("[k for k,v in d.items() if v!=defa]")
9.79900360107e-05
```

Comment: The `default_factory` bit is gold, was looking for it all over the place. Thanks! :)

Comment: `dir(defaultdict)` helped!

Comment: could be faster with: `[k for k,v in d.items() if v!=d.default_factory()]`, and pre-compute `default_factory` value.

Comment: I've added the time comparison of both the methods! precomputing default_factory value definitely reduces time! Plus one for that!

Comment: what do you mean time comparision here? execution time? or speed?

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed what is the difference between execution time and speed?

Comment: I'm surprised that using `d.items()` slows that down. Maybe using more iterations would allow a better measure (like done in the `timeit` module)

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran first of all i will say thanks for your clear explanation and great answer.. but from your command, here time says your manual execution speed will say real duration... if you check your code again will know that.

Comment: >>> def funct(a=None,b=None,c=None):
...   s=time.time()
...   eval(a)
...   print time.time()-s
... 
>>> funct("[k for k,v in d.items() if v!=d.default_factory()]")
5.31673431396e-05
>>> funct("[i for i in d if d[i]!=d.default_factory()]")
0.000155210494995
>>> funct("[i for i in d if d[i]!=d.default_factory()]")
0.000157117843628
>>> funct("[k for k,v in d.items() if v!=d.default_factory()]")
0.000166893005371
>>>

Comment: if you made delay to execute(human delay) will cause time difference which  not means items() slow...  check my above comment. sorry for unclear. cant make it clear in comments

Comment: and human delay, isnt feasible. The method calculates the start and end time, so where does human delay come from!? >>> funct("[k for k,v in d.items() if v!=d.default_factory()]")
0.000102996826172
>>> funct("[i for i in d if d[i]!=d.default_factory()]")
4.79221343994e-05
>>> funct("[i for i in d if d[i]!=d.default_factory()]")
3.50475311279e-05
>>> funct("[k for k,v in d.items() if v!=d.default_factory()]")
5.50746917725e-05

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `Originally, Python items() built a real list of tuples and returned that. That could potentially take a lot of extra memory.` as quoted  on [stackoverflow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458437/what-is-the-difference-between-dict-items-and-dict-iteritems)

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran if run it again will understand.. just swap it run... run .items() first and another one next.. it start from your func def. you ran through terminal so you hit one by one. its start and end time

Answer (score 0):

`[key for key in d.keys() if key != 'default']`

Answer (score 0):

`default_factory()` is a callable and need not return the same value each time!

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from random import random
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: random())
>>> d[1]
0.7411252345322932
>>> d[2]
0.09672701444816645
>>> d.keys()
dict_keys([1, 2])
>>> d.default_factory()
0.06277993247659297
>>> d.default_factory()
0.4388136209046052
>>> d.keys()
dict_keys([1, 2])
>>> [k for k in d.keys() if d[k] != d.default_factory()]
[1, 2]
```