# How to get the key from value in a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python

```
d[key] = value
```

but how to get the keys from value?

For example:

```
a = {"horse": 4, "hot": 10, "hangover": 1, "hugs": 10}
b = 10

print(do_something with 10 to get ["hot", "hugs"])
```

Comment: This is not what a map was made for, it should be the other way around.
Why do you need to look for entries by their values?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can write a list comprehension to pull out the matching keys.

```
print([k for k,v in a.items() if v == b])
```

Answer (score 10):

Something like this can do it:

```
for key, value in a.iteritems():
    if value == 10:
        print key
```

If you want to save the associated keys to a value in a list, you edit the above example as follows:

```
keys = []
for key, value in a.iteritems():
    if value == 10:
        print key
        keys.append(key)
```

You can also do that in a list comprehension as pointed out in an other answer.

```
b = 10 
keys = [key for key, value in a.iteritems() if value == b]
```

Note that in python 3, `dict.items` is equivalent to `dict.iteritems` in python 2, check this for more details: [What is the difference between dict.items() and dict.iteritems()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458437/what-is-the-difference-between-dict-items-and-dict-iteritems?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: closest you'll ever get to what OP wants