# How to access single key from multiple values of a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

`{'Sensor': ['Data 0', 'Data 1'], 'Microphone': ['Microphone']}` is my dictionary.From `Data 0` I need to access `Sensor`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the key from value in a dictionary in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45635242/how-to-get-the-key-from-value-in-a-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: @HS-nebula  In that question there are only one string value per key, so not exactly duplicate

Comment: Add some more information in the question. Write your required output in the Question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `list-comprehension` to iterate over dict and check if `Data 0` is in values(which is list):

```
a = {'Sensor': ['Data 0', 'Data 1'], 'Microphone': ['Microphone']}

print([k for k,v in a.items() if 'Data 0' in v][0])
```

Output:

```
'Sensor'
```