# Python: How to iterate through a dictionary using a list, instead of counter

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with the following structure:

```
results =

 {1: {'A': 10,
     'B' : 11,
     'C': 12},
 5: {'A': 20,
     'B' : 21,
     'C': 22}}
```

I have tried to iterate through this dictionary using this for loop:

```
total_A = []
for key in results:
  total_A.append(results[key]["A"])
  print total_A
```

But it is not working, because it is inputting key as 1 and 2 each time it loops. How am i able to iterate through the results dictionary using index as 1 and 5? (they are of type integer)

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: Which version of python are you using? This seems to work in python 3.

Comment: It also behaves as expected on Python 2.6.6. What output are _you_ getting, and what output do you expect to get?

Answer (score 3):

Try this. It will loop through your dictionary keys.

```
for key in results.keys():
```

Like this:

```
total_A = []
for key in results.keys():
  total_A.append(results[key]["A"])

print total_A
```

Result is

```
[10, 20]
```

Comment: Hey, this does not return the "5" key-value pair, only 1 (i'm using python 2.7). Sorry , i wasn't clear, i want to return in  a list values for "A" in both 1 and 5

Comment: It does for me.

Comment: Edited the answer with an example with your code (moved print total_A out of the for loop, though)

Comment: Ok thanks, yeah i had to move print total_A out of the loop

Comment: Recommend using `for key,value in results.iteritems()` (python2) or `for key,value in results.items()` (python3), rather than doing a second lookup in the results dict.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you could do

`for key, value in results.items():
    total_A.append(value["A"])`

Then `value` will contain the value of the dictionary element, and you don't have to do the `results[key]` lookup explicitly.

Comment: Note that while `dict.items()` is standard approach in python3; for the OP it would be good to (also) include `dict.iteritems()` as it is arguably a more standard/common python2.7 approach. See here for why there is a difference, despite both "working" in python2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458437/what-is-the-difference-between-dict-items-and-dict-iteritems (and also that `dict.viewitems()` exists in python2.7, when you expect to alter the dict during iteration)