# How to get multiple max key values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's say I have a dictionary:

```
data = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c': 3, 'd': 3}
```

I want to get the maximum value(s) in the dictionary. So far, I have been just doing:

```
max(zip(data.values(), data.keys()))[1]
```

but I'm aware that I could be missing another max value. What would be the most efficient way to approach this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on your example, it seems like you're looking for **the key(s) which map to the maximum value.**  You could use a list comprehension:

```
[k for k, v in data.items() if v == max(data.values())]
# ['c', 'd']
```

If you have a large dictionary, break this into two lines to avoid calculating max for as many items as you have:

```
mx = max(data.values())
[k for k, v in data.items() if v == mx]
```

In Python 2.x you will need `.iteritems()`.

Comment: I don't think you need `.iteritems()`. (I am on Python 2.7)

Comment: @user405892 I guess it might not be needed, but might be more memory efficient?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458437/what-is-the-difference-between-dict-items-and-dict-iteritems

Comment: Ah, didn't know that. Yeah, probably better to use that then.

Answer (score 5):

You could try collecting reverse `value -> key` pairs in a `defaultdict`, then output the values with the highest key:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def get_max_value(data):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for key, value in data.items():
        d[value].append(key)
    return max(d.items())[1]
```

Which Outputs:

```py
>>> get_max_value({'a':1, 'b':2, 'c': 3, 'd': 3})
['c', 'd']
>>> get_max_value({'a': 10, 'b': 10, 'c': 4, 'd': 5})
['a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, find what is the max value that occurs in the dictionary.  If you are trying to create a list of all the max value(s), then try something like this:

```
    data = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c': 3, 'd': 3}
    max_value = data.get(max(data))
    list_num_max_value = []
    for letter in data:
      if data.get(letter) == max_value:
        list_num_max_value.append(max_value)
    print (list_num_max_value)
```

Please let me know if that's not what you are trying to do and I will guide you through the right process.