# Parsing List of Dictionaries with multiple same Keys

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I started with this list of dictionaries.

```
[{'allow_day_and_time': {'day': 'Monday', 'start': 9, 'end': 18}}, 
{'allow_day_and_time': {'day': 'Tuesday', 'start': 9, 'end': 18}}, 
{'allow_day_and_time': {'day': 'Wednesday', 'start': 9, 'end': 18}}, 
{'allow_day_and_time': {'day': 'Thursday', 'start': 9, 'end': 18}}, 
{'allow_day_and_time': {'day': 'Friday', 'start': 9, 'end': 18}}]
```

I applied this.

```
index = 0
    while index < len(availability_constraints):
        for key in availability_constraints[index]:
            print(availability_constraints[index][key])
        index += 1
```

results in

```
{'day': 'Monday', 'start': 9, 'end': 18}
{'day': 'Tuesday', 'start': 9, 'end': 18}
{'day': 'Wednesday', 'start': 9, 'end': 18}
{'day': 'Thursday', 'start': 9, 'end': 18}
{'day': 'Friday', 'start': 9, 'end': 18}
```

It's possible that I could be returned multiple start and end vales for any of days returned for example Monday start 9, finish 11, Monday Start 13, finish 18.

What I'm struggling with is how to get the start and finish time for the days retuned keeping in mind I might be returned multiple start and end times for the same day.

Any pointers would be a big help.

Comment: What will the input look like if you have multiple entries for a single day? Are you doing anything other than just printing out the entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your complete data may look somehow like this:

```
[{'allow_day_and_time': {'day': 'Monday', 'start': 9, 'end': 18}}, 
{'allow_day_and_time': {'day': 'Tuesday', 'start': 9, 'end': 18}}, 
{'allow_day_and_time': {'day': 'Wednesday', 'start': 9, 'end': 18}}, 
{'allow_day_and_time': {'day': 'Thursday', 'start': 9, 'end': 18}}, 
{'allow_day_and_time': {'day': 'Friday', 'start': 9, 'end': 18}},
{'allow_day_and_time': {'day': 'Monday', 'start': 13, 'end': 21}}, 
{'allow_day_and_time': {'day': 'Tuesday', 'start': 13, 'end': 21}}, 
{'allow_day_and_time': {'day': 'Wednesday', 'start': 13, 'end': 21}}, 
{'allow_day_and_time': {'day': 'Thursday', 'start': 13, 'end': 21}}, 
{'allow_day_and_time': {'day': 'Friday', 'start': 13, 'end': 21}}]
```

Since your data is a `list` of `dictionary` items, you can [access the `dictionary`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm) simply by supplying the `key` within `[]` bracket, or, you can retrieve the `key` and `value` using [`dictionary.iteritems()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458437/what-is-the-difference-between-dict-items-and-dict-iteritems)

### Iterating with `dictionary.iteritems()`

```
In [  ]: index = 0
    ...: while index < len(availability_constraints):
    ...:     for key, value in availability_constraints[index].iteritems():
    ...:         print(key, value)
    ...:     index += 1
    ...: 
('allow_day_and_time', {'start': 9, 'end': 18, 'day': 'Monday'})
('allow_day_and_time', {'start': 9, 'end': 18, 'day': 'Tuesday'})
('allow_day_and_time', {'start': 9, 'end': 18, 'day': 'Wednesday'})
('allow_day_and_time', {'start': 9, 'end': 18, 'day': 'Thursday'})
('allow_day_and_time', {'start': 9, 'end': 18, 'day': 'Friday'})
('allow_day_and_time', {'start': 13, 'end': 21, 'day': 'Monday'})
('allow_day_and_time', {'start': 13, 'end': 21, 'day': 'Tuesday'})
('allow_day_and_time', {'start': 13, 'end': 21, 'day': 'Wednesday'})
('allow_day_and_time', {'start': 13, 'end': 21, 'day': 'Thursday'})
('allow_day_and_time', {'start': 13, 'end': 21, 'day': 'Friday'})
```

Let's say you are querying the start of `Monday`, you can use `if` and `==` operator to check if the `value` of that particular element of the list is referring to `Monday`:

```
In [  ]: index = 0
    ...: while index < len(availability_constraints):
    ...:     for key, value in availability_constraints[index].iteritems():
    ...:         if value['day'] == 'Monday':
    ...:             print("Start: {:>4}, Finish: {:>4}".format(value['start'], value['end']))
    ...:     index += 1
    ...: 
Start:    9, Finish:   18
Start:   13, Finish:   21
```

### Iterating with `[]` and supplying hardcoded `key`

Another more straightforward/hardcoded, which may not be the best programming practice, is shown below:

```
In [  ]: for a_day in availability_constraints:
    ...:     if a_day['allow_day_and_time']['day'] == 'Monday':
    ...:         print("Start: {:>4}, Finish: {:>4}".format(
    ...:          a_day['allow_day_and_time']['start'],
    ...:          a_day['allow_day_and_time']['end']))
    ...:         
    ...:         
Start:    9, Finish:   18
Start:   13, Finish:   21
```

We can also introduce indirection for better maintenance:

```
In [  ]: key = 'allow_day_and_time'
    ...: target_day = 'Monday'
    ...: begin = 'start'
    ...: finish = 'end'
    ...: for a_day in availability_constraints:
    ...:     if a_day[key]['day'] == target_day:
    ...:         print("Start: {:>4}, Finish: {:>4}".format(
    ...:          a_day[key][begin],
    ...:          a_day[key][finish]))
    ...:         
    ...:         
Start:    9, Finish:   18
Start:   13, Finish:   21
```

### Conclusion: The pythonic way

Check this [link](https://pyformat.info/) for pythonic `string formatting`

```
In [  ]: for a_day in availability_constraints:
    ...:     for key, value in a_day.iteritems():
    ...:         if value['day'] == 'Monday':
    ...:             print("Start: {:>4}, Finish: {:>4}".format(value['start'], value['end']))
Start:    9, Finish:   18
Start:   13, Finish:   21
```

Which programming style is the best? Well, I'm pretty opinionated myself, so I believe it depends on your preference unless you want this program to be optimized :D

Comment: Anthony this was just what I needed, also helps me understand much more with the multiple examples given, thank you!

Comment: @Lee no worries, glad could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to find all days associated with common start and end values:

```
import itertools
def time_key(x:dict):
  _d = x['allow_day_and_time']
  return _d['start'], _d['end']

d = [{'allow_day_and_time': {'day': 'Monday', 'start': 9, 'end': 18}}, {'allow_day_and_time': {'day': 'Tuesday', 'start': 9, 'end': 18}}, {'allow_day_and_time': {'day': 'Wednesday', 'start': 9, 'end': 18}}, {'allow_day_and_time': {'day': 'Thursday', 'start': 9, 'end': 18}}, {'allow_day_and_time': {'day': 'Friday', 'start': 9, 'end': 18}}, {'allow_day_and_time': {'day': 'Monday', 'start': 13, 'end': 21}}, {'allow_day_and_time': {'day': 'Tuesday', 'start': 13, 'end': 21}}, {'allow_day_and_time': {'day': 'Wednesday', 'start': 13, 'end': 21}}, {'allow_day_and_time': {'day': 'Thursday', 'start': 13, 'end': 21}}, {'allow_day_and_time': {'day': 'Friday', 'start': 13, 'end': 21}}]
new_d = [{'start':_s, 'end':_e, 'days':[i['allow_day_and_time']['day'] for i in b]} for [_s, _e], b in itertools.groupby(sorted(d, key=time_key), key=time_key)]
```

Output:

```
[{'start': 9, 'end': 18, 'days': ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']}, {'start': 13, 'end': 21, 'days': ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']}]
```