# Why would I want to use function: 'items' to process nested dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say we have a dictionary inside a dictionary:

```
people = {
           0: {'name': 'John', 'age': 27, 'sex': 'Male'},
           4: {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 22, 'sex': 'Female'},
           7: {'name': 'Agness', 'age': 25, 'sex': 'Female'}
         }
```

What is a faster way to go through that dictionary?
I saw on Internet solution:

```
for p_id, p_info in people.items():
    print("\nPerson ID:", p_id)        
    for key in p_info:
        print(key + ':', p_info[key])
```

However *items* function creates from scratch(?) a list of tuples.

I feel like going through dictionary that way is faster:

```
for key in people:
    for value in people[key]:
        print(value)
```

Am I wrong? If yes, why?

Comment: I think your best way would be benchmarking how long both take with the time module

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458437/what-is-the-difference-between-dict-items-and-dict-iteritems

Comment: I suppose you are using python2. In this case you have an equivalent method named `iteritems` that iterates over the key-value pairs, without creating the list.