# How to fetch the keys , values from response using python and append it.?

Tags: python, json

I have a response in this format and using python code to fetch the key and values.

```
def test()
data={u'Application': u'e2e', u'Cost center': u'qwerty', u'Environment': u'E2E', u'e2e3': u'aktest1', u'e2etes

for k,v in data.items():
    new = {}
print('forloop before')
for k,v in data.items():
    print (k)
    print (v)
    new["key"] = k
    new["tags"] = []
for d in v:
    flds = list(d)
    new["tags"].append({"key": k, "values": flds})
    print(new["tags"])
test()
```

I am getting output as 
  [{'key': 'S68e2e', 'values': ['f']}, {'key': 'S68e2e', 'values': ['u']}, {'key': 'S68e2e', 'values': ['n']}, {'key': 'S68e2e', 'values': ['c']}, {'key': 'S68e2e', 'values': ['t']}, {'key': 'S68e2e', 'values': ['i']}, {'key': 'S68e2e', 'values': ['o']}, {'key': 'S68e2e', 'values': ['n']}]

which is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `data.items()`

```
for k, v in data.items():
    print(f'{k}: {v}')
```

Output

```
app: e2e
Cost: qwerty
Environment: E2E
e2e3: test
e2etest: at2
Se2e: function
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending whether it's python 2 or 3 you should do the following:

```
# Python 2
for k,v in data.iteritems():
   ...
```

```
# Python 3
for k,v in data.items():
   ...
```

See more details on `.items()` and `.iteritems()` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458437/what-is-the-difference-between-dict-items-and-dict-iteritems) SO thread.