# Difference between df.items() and df.iteritems()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, memory

Pandas documentation for [`df.items()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.items.html) says;

> Iterate over (column name, Series) pairs.

The exact same definition can be found for [`df.iteritems()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iteritems.html) as well. Both seem to be doing the same thing.

However, I was curious whether there is any difference between these two, as there is between `dict.items()` and `dict.iteritems()` according to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458437/what-is-the-difference-between-dict-items-and-dict-iteritems-in-python2). Apparently, `dict.items()` created a real list of tuples (in python2) potentially taking a lot of memory while `dict.iteritems()` returns a generator.

Is this the case with `df.items()` and `df.iteritems()`? Is `df.iteritems()` faster for dataframes having a large number of columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are exactly the same, there is no difference. You can see the source code of both [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py#L1149-L1160). The `iteritems` method is really this (except for the type hints and doc decorator):

```py
def iteritems(self):
    yield from self.items()
```

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between the two methods is that `df.items()` returns a list of tuples, while `df.iteritems()` returns a generator.

This means that `df.items()` will take up more memory, as it needs to store the entire list of tuples in memory. `df.iteritems()`, on the other hand, will only store a small amount of data in memory at a time, which makes it more efficient for large DataFrames.

Here is a link to an explanation of generators in Python:
[Understanding generators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python)